# Friendly urls for module, how to remove a module from url?

Tags: prestashop-1.5

How to set a friendly url for my module page, actually I need just to remove a `module` from my `url: http://mystore.com/module/mymodule` and it's must to be just `http://mystore.com/mymodule` ?

`[`**1**. **upd** `]`

I think it would be not right if I get rid of a `module` in a preferences and set `{module}{/:controller}` instead of `module/{module}{/:controller}`

[image: preferences]

So I need this url only for my module, not for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a page for that module page.

"Preferences > SEO & URLs" click the add new. under the pages you can see your module page